# What is the original Sanskrit of Mahabharata Book 3, Chapter 188

Tags: mahabharata

I would like to see the original Sanskrit for the following verse (or verses).

> Governed by my ordinance, men wander within my body, their senses
> overwhelmed by me. They move not according to their will but as they
> are moved by me.
>
> [Mahabharata Book 3 Chapter 188](https://Mahabharata%20Book%203%20Chapter%20188)

Comment: Please approve the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are different editions of Mahabharata, some times the chapter number are different. In the Sanskrit version I found, the corresponding shloka is present in Chapter 187

> **Sanskrit Shlokas**
>
> 21 पराप्नुवन्ति नरा विप्र यत्कृत्वा कर्मशॊभनम
> सत्यं दानं तपॊ चॊग्रम अहिंसा चैव जन्तुषु
>
> 22 मद्विधानेन विहिता मम देहविहारिणः
> मयाभिभूत विज्ञाना विचेष्टन्ते न कामतः
>
> **English Transliteration**
>
> 21 prāpnuvanti narā vipra yatkṛtvā karmaśobhanam
> satyaṃ dānaṃ tapo cogram ahiṃsā caiva jantuṣu
>
> 22 madvidhānena vihitā mama dehavihāriṇaḥ
> mayābhibhūta vijñānā viceṣṭante na kāmataḥ
>
> [Mahabharata 3.187.21-22](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03187.htm)
>
> **English Translation**
>
> And, O Brahmana, whatever is obtained by men by the practice of truth,
> charity, ascetic austerities, and peace and harmlessness towards all
> creatures, and such other handsome deeds, is obtained because of my
> arrangements. Governed by my ordinance, men wander within my body,
> their senses overwhelmed by me. They move not according to their will
> but as they are moved by me.
>
> [Mahabharata Book 3 Chapter 188](https://mahabharata%20book%203%20chapter%20188/)